# Collection update not triggering reaction in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to build an active/inactive indicator into a chat application in Meteor. To do that, I need to keep track of the time of each user's most recent activity on every client. Whenever a user sends a message, this line is called:

```
People.update({ name: login }, { $set: { activity: new Date() }});
```

I can see the data changing in the database with the `meteor mongo` command. In another part of the file, I have some code that looks like this:

```
Template.user_listing.people = function () {
  return People.find();
}
```

In my code, this function only gets called when items are added to or removed from the People collection. The first code example, `People.update(...)`, doesn't trigger a reaction, and I was under the impression that it should. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would check two things here: 1) can People.find() see the user in question?  2) is the update running successfully?  One way to check is to add a callback and log the (error,result) arguments.  I've had some updates fail silently, which is why I mention this.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to avoid variables like `x` and `y` in questions or answers.

Renaming `x` to `user_listing`. Shouldn't it look like this,

```
Template.user_listing.people = function () {
  return People.find();
}
```

Now you have the database cursor which can be passed to `#each` in template.

The template looks like this,

```
<template name="user_listing">
  {{#each people}}
      Who: {{name}}
      Recent activity: {{activity}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Assuming that you have,

```
People = new Meteor.Collection('people'); // or whatever your collection name is
```

http://docs.meteor.com/#templates has an example. Verify with that.

Comment: Apologies. The real code looked more like your example. Edited to be more descriptive. The problem persists even after that change though.

Comment: Can you pastebin the template html?

Answer (score 0):

Meteor has 'parts' that are reactive. This means that whenever a reactive source changes, the computations (every other variable and functions that use that reactive source) refreshes (re-runs).
You can achieve what you described by using subscribing to the people collection. Subscriptions are reactive. When you change a people document, the changes will be pushed to the client as well and because the subscriptions are reactive, your template will be updated with the new stuff...

TLDR: In order to automatically receive db updates in the frontend you need to remove the autopublish package and use publish and subscribe, like i'm doing bellow.

```
// client js
Template.user_listing.onCreated(function () {
  this.subscribe('people');
});

Template.user_listing.helpers({
  getPeople: function () {
    return People.find();
  }
});

// then, when a user sends a message you trigger  the update
People.update({ name: login }, { $set: { activity: new Date() }});

// and in your html template
<template name="user_listing">
  {{#each people}}
    Who: {{name}}
    Recent activity: {{activity}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

// server
Meteor.publish('people', function () {
  return People.find();
});

// on both server and client
People = new Meteor.Collection('people');
```

Read more on publish and subscribe and follow an example:
https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe